# jndi binding on jboss4.2.3 and ejb3

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, jndi

I am trying to deploy a stateless ejb on jboss 4.2.3 using ejb3 annotations.  Everything builds and deploys correctly, and I do not get any errors when jboss starts up.  However the ejb is not getting bound to any JNDI location for lookup when I look at the bindings in jboss.  Below is what I have for my ejb.

Remote

```
@Remote
public interface TestWebService {

public String TestWebMethod(String param1, String param2);

}
```

Stateless EJB

```
@Stateless
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="TestWeb")
@Remote(TestWebService.class)

public class TestWebServiceBean implements TestWebService{

public String TestWebMethod(String param1, String param2) {
    System.out.println("HELLO "+param1+" "+param2);
    return "Welcome!!";
}

 }
```

I have tried not having the @Remote and @RemoteBinding and it doesn't make a difference.  I have also added and ejb-jar.xml file (which should not be needed with ejb3) and that does not appear to make a difference.  Below is the output I see in the jboss log on startup.

```
installing MBean: jboss.j2ee:ear=ejb_web_service_ear-0.0.1-    SNAPSHOT.ear,jar=ejb_web_service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,name=TestWebServiceBean,service=EJB3 with dependencies:
 21:56:00,633 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.tomax.ejb.TestWebServiceBean ejbName: TestWebServiceBean
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out, so in case anyone else has similar problems hopefully this will help.  First I had the incorrect package for the annotations in jboss 4.2.3, they should be org.jboss.anotation.ejb.*  for this version of jboss, in 5 and up this has changed.  Also there were some additional dependency jars in my ear file that should not have been included since they are provided by the container.  Once I removed those then it worked.

Comment: +1 for coming back and reporting what you found. You should mark your own answer as accepted.